# Adding a column to multiple tables in MS Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database with almost 200 tables. I would like to rename the fields of many of these (to make it easier when I analyze the data in R). I've discovered that you can't simply rename fields in Access, but have to do it the hard way of adding a new column, transferring data, then dropping the old column.

Is there a way to do this for multiple tables (or multiple tables and columns) at once using SQL?

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE * FROM MSysObjects ADD COLUMN colname NUMBER
```

as well as this:

```
ALTER TABLE table1, table2, table3... ADD COLUMN colname NUMBER
```

but neither seem to work.

Is this possible at all? Does anyone know how to code this?

Answer (score 2):

*"Is there a way to do this for multiple tables (or multiple tables and columns) at once using SQL?"*

No.  That is beyond the capability of Access SQL. You will need to execute a series of statements, and each can only alter a single table.

You could create a VBA procedure to build and execute those statements.  But, if you're willing to use VBA, consider simply renaming the columns via the DAO object model.

Here is a simple example from the Immediate window:

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("some_text").Name
some_text
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("some_text").Name = "some_text2"
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("some_text2").Name
some_text2
```

Comment: Thanks, Hans. Is it possible to do what I want in an actual SQL program (e.g. MySQL, SQLite)?

Comment: Perhaps, but I can't offer any help for those.

Comment: @Paul re: "Is it possible to do what I want in [some other database]?" - Generally speaking, no. At least I'm not aware of any databases that offer a "global update" feature to change the *structure* of database objects. (By the way, remember that you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) an answer if you find it helpful. Accepted answers help others recognize that your question has been resolved.)